# Stable Diffusion Videos - DLL load failed while importing _ufuncs: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: winapi, dll, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to run the Stable Diffusion Videos package and have installed the package and logged into Hugging Face. When I try to run the provided code from the package's GitHub page, I run into the `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ufuncs: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.` error. I have tried various solutions to this error but so far none of the solutions have worked.

I'm running Windows 11, 64 bit, and Python 3.10. I've read about missing dll files but am unsure how to find / install them to possibly fix this problem.

```
from stable_diffusion_videos import StableDiffusionWalkPipeline
import torch

pipeline = StableDiffusionWalkPipeline.from_pretrained(
    "CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4",
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    revision="fp16",
).to("cuda")

video_path = pipeline.walk(
    prompts=['a cat', 'a dog'],
    seeds=[42, 1337],
    num_interpolation_steps=3,
    height=512,  # use multiples of 64 if > 512. Multiples of 8 if < 512.
    width=512,   # use multiples of 64 if > 512. Multiples of 8 if < 512.
    output_dir='dreams',        # Where images/videos will be saved
    name='animals_test',        # Subdirectory of output_dir where images/videos will be saved
    guidance_scale=8.5,         # Higher adheres to prompt more, lower lets model take the wheel
    num_inference_steps=50,     # Number of diffusion steps per image generated. 50 is good default
)
```

Comment: from . import _ufuncs
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ufuncs: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

This is the specific error I'm receiving

Comment: 32/64 bit mismatch with dll or its dependencies

Comment: @DavidHeffernan how would I fix this?

Comment: First of all you need to work out which DLL is failing to load. Don't you get a traceback? If you do get a traceback, it should be in the question.